# Парсер HTML/XHTML на С++

Tags: html, c++, qt, парсер

Существует ли в природе парсер невалидного HTML на С++ / QT?

Требования:

- без зависимостей, особенно бинарных, привязанных к конкретной архитектуре;
- без привязки к UI и app event loop (hello QWebEngine), чтоб можно было использовать его, например, в Android-приложении (QT Quick);
- поиск XPath и CSS Selectors, descendants/ancestor оси (hello Gumbo)

Альтернативы в других языках: 
Java: Jsoup, Python: Grab/BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

Не вполне понятно, что такое "невалидный HTML" и насколько допустимо его отличие от стандарта. 
Посмотри, например, http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html#htmlReadFile (с атрибутом HTML_PARSE_RECOVER).

Comment: имеется ввиду, что парсить его стандартными средствами QT, как обычный xml не выйдет

Answer (score 0):

Если устраивает HTML4, то можно попробовать libxml2
http://xmlsoft.org/
Но под андроид нужно будет iconv собрать, у меня остались смутные воспоминания, что определенные танцы с бубном там будут нужны.
http://xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html#Compilatio
из зависомостей он требует libz, iconv
MIT лицензия